# Sails database configuration issue with postgresql

Tags: sails.js, sails-postgresql

I upgrade sails to 1.0, I resolved all the other errors but not able to resolved database connection issue,

It will be really helpful if anyone can reply on this.

```
module.exports.datastores = {
  localDiskDb: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk'
  },
  postgreSql: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    // url: 'postgresql://admin:root@localhost:5432/testdb',
    // ssl: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'testdb'
  },
};
```

**Important Error Logs**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using password which contains `%`
after changing the password sails successfully connected to postgresql.

It mostly looks like bug with `Sails v1` or `Sails-pgsql` adapter.